# Cannot read property 'state' of undefined in API call

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component in react

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cityName: "",
      weather: ""
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=.....&q=${this.state.cityName}&aqi=no`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({ weather: json});
      });
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({cityName: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <center>
        <p><font color="bluesky" size="10">Weather</font></p>
        <div class="card-body">
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Type the name of city"></input>
          <h3>{this.state.cityName}</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" onClick={this.componentDidMount}>Check weather</button>
        </div>
      </center>
    );
  }
}
```

and for this line of code
`` fetch(`https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=...&q=${this.state.cityName}&aqi=no`) ``
I get the next error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined". I am new to react, can somebody help me to fix this error ?

Comment: why are you calling `componentDidMount` on button click?

Comment: Because I need to display the data from API after the button is clicked.

Comment: ```componentDidMount()``` is a special method of React lifecycle that executes its code when component is mounted, you have to fetch data in a custom function, not in ```componentDidMount()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling component lifecycle method to handle form submit. Create a submitHandler just as you've the changeHandler and it should work fine.

```
onSubmit = () => {
fetch(`https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=.....&q=${this.state.cityName}&aqi=no`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    this.setState({ weather: json});
  });
}
```

The button will be configured as:

```
<button className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" onClick={this.onSubmit}>Check weather</button>
```

Pro tip: Use **arrow functions** to define custom methods in your component.

Note: You need to configure the API key and handle the response correctly,use console.log(json) in the second .then() and see what you get.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cityName: "",
      weather: ""
    }
  }

  onSubmit = () => {
    fetch(`https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=.....&q=${this.state.cityName}&aqi=no`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({ weather: json});
      });
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({cityName: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <center>
        <p><font color="bluesky" size="10">Weather</font></p>
        <div class="card-body">
          <input type="text" value={this.state.cityName} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Type the name of city"></input>
          <h3>{this.state.weather}</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" onClick={this.onSubmit}>Check weather</button>
        </div>
      </center>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! Keep going :)

Comment: super pro tip: move to reack hooks   and functional components...

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount()` is a function where its code is executed when the component is mounted, so when you fetch data with in `componentDidMount()`, the `${this.state.cityName}` in the URL is still equal to nothing (`cityName: ""` in your default state)

1. You need to set a default value to `cityName` like

```
this.state = {
      cityName: "London",
      weather: ""
}
```

or

2. You need to fetch only after the user pressed a button

```
search() {
 // fetch here
}

<button className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" onClick={this.search}>Check weather</button>
```

And by the way you need to remove `onClick={this.componentDidMount}` from the button because `componentDidMount` is automatically called when the component is mounting, better replace this by `onClick={this.search}` and create a `search` function where you can fetch datas

Comment: I tried both solutions and I get the same error.